# What is the entry criteria for lightning-ready app

Tags: lightning

I searched through the internet and was surprised that I didn't see much related information. As Eric mentioned in my other post: [Any good reason for using lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145478/any-good-reason-for-using-lightning-component) . Every app should be lightning ready before 2017-3. So it is almost critical for us to prepare for it now. What is the criteria for an app to be lightning ready in App Exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to run our app in Lightning Experience Enable org and fix if something is broken. Then we need to update Salesforce that our app is lightning ready.

As per Salesforce docs:

**How do I get my apps ready for the new Lightning Experience?**

User experience (UX) is one of the most important aspects of this initiative — it’s practically in the name: “Lightning Experience”. Accordingly, we want to help our partners evolve their applications to this new era of UX.

So what does this mean for your existing app? Many apps feature customizations, including custom objects, custom buttons, Visualforce pages. In preparation for the Lightning Experience release, all partners should test their apps to ensure functionality continues working properly in the new experience. Partners can also get their apps designated as “Lightning Ready”. Apps that are Lightning Ready will work in Lightning Experience and offer a more consistent experience with other Lightning pages. If your app uses standard Salesforce UI, objects, page layouts, but no custom Visualforce pages, then you should expect them to display properly in the new Lightning Experience with the new look and feel. In general, Visualforce pages will work in the new UI, but they should be tested to ensure all features are properly supported and functioning correctly.

To earn the Lightning Ready certification, Visualforce pages in apps should be updated to offer a more consistent user experience with Lightning. To assist in this effort, we are publishing the Lightning Design System, which is formal documentation around all the styles that make up the Lightning Experience across all form factors. The Lightning Design System is available to all, and will be made GA through an open-source project on GitHub for Dreamforce. It can be used to design apps built on the Salesforce Platform as well as on other platforms. https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/

[Are you ready for the new lightning experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2015/08/are-you-ready-for-the-new-lightning-experience.html)

Comment: So in short, we need to test the functionalities by ourselves. Make VF pages using SLDS and then open a ticket to inform Salesforce. Is that right?

Comment: @LanceShi yes but VF pages should be tested to ensure all features are properly supported and functioning correctly.

Comment: Yep, I mentioned that already. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @LanceShi Added more details in case you need more info .

Answer (score 3):

You will find all the resources [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/isv/2015/08/are-you-ready-for-the-new-lightning-experience.html) to help you understand what is lightning ready

For lightning Ready Certification, here are key things SFDC looks in
    your application :

1. Use SLDS Design Systems for CSS in your visualforce.
2. Test for supported browsers .(IE,Firefox,Chrome,Safari)
3. Make sure your app is responsive and at a viewport minimum of 1024px
   wide and a maximum of 1920px wide.
4. Make sure that your app responds elegantly when the tabs are switched
5. Do use the new Salesforce Sans typeface. It should not be accompanied by any other typeface, with the exception of your logotype.

   > Try to Align with Basic Page Layouts like salesforce Edit ,List view and Detail View on Lightning experience .

In short your App should be functional in Lightning Experience and the CSS should match as closely as possible to Lightning Experience .

You will need to open a case with support and they will do a sanity check to see if your app works in lightning experience and you are good to go .Please note you need not build true lightning components to pass lightning ready check .

Answer (score 0):

We need following things to get Lightning ready designation.

1. App should be responsive and at a view-port minimum of 1024px wide and a maximum of 1920px wide.
2. App should be functional in Lightning Experience and the CSS should match as closely as possible to Lightning Experience.
3. Update App Exchange listing with new screenshots showing how is app running in Lightning Experience.
4. Log a case to SF and get your Lightning Ready designation -

Please find the reference [here](https://org62.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#000000000062/a/30000000bwUm/Y6To9GKaWAJeRlbaUReGYz4FHR.xW6xLcwahCgIO7DI).