# How can I get "Lightning Accredited" badge for my company on Appexchange?

Tags: lightning, appexchange

[image]

I want this badge for my company.
(I am talking about blue color badge "LIGHTNING ACCREDITED".)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the entry criteria for lightning-ready app](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146349/what-is-the-entry-criteria-for-lightning-ready-app)

Comment: It looks different then lightning ready badge.It seems it is available for consultants.Looking for more information...

Comment: @TusharSharma, this isn't a duplicate of that question. There are specific requirements for that are documented in the Partner Community. I recommend you ask your question there where you'll get the latest information on what's required for the program.

Answer (score 1):

There is specific requirements you have to fullfill to earn the Lightning Accridation badge for your company's consulting profile.

**Trailhead Migration Trail & Super Badge:**
[image]

You can download this ppt (https://partners.salesforce.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0683A000005nXC9?asPdf=false&operationContext=CHATTER) for more details.

Can I suggest you join this group (https://partners.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009PWP) in Partner Community to keep yourself updated?

Thanks,
Debanjan