# Can Lightning App be published to AppExchange and visible in both Classic and Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning, appexchange

I want to make an app and publish it to the AppExchange and I want it to be available in both Classic and Lightning Experience. I went through [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146349/what-is-the-entry-criteria-for-lightning-ready-app)
 and through [lightning design system](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/)
. So the advice is to make a classic app and adjust Visualforce to comply with lightning design system. Is this the only way (using Visualforce and making it lightning ready) or I can create a "Lightning App" from the Lightning UI like on the image below:
[image]
and add Lightning pages to it? Will it also be "Lightning ready" app?

So my main confusion is the difference beween **Lightning App** and **Lightning ready app**. (by "Ligtning App" I don't mean the Aura Lightning Application which is a container for Lightning components, but the app like the one on the image above)

Can I create a Lightning app (by clicking on "New Lightning App") and publish it to AppExchange? If I can, will it be available in both Lightning experience and classic UI?

Comment: Please go through this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/175594/app-exchange-lightning-ready-concept/175616#175616

Comment: @PiyushKumar it doesn't answer my question. It also talks about visualforce and UI/UX. My question is about "Lightning App" type of app and is it going to be available in the classic UI.

Comment: Lightning App directly not available in Salesforce Classic UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Piyush Kumar and @Scott Morrison answered my question in comments. So in order for an app to be available in both classic and lightning experience, you need to use visualforce and make it "lightning ready". You can use lightning components in visualforce pages using [lightning out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm)

Tnx guys!

Comment: That is correct. Pro tip: if you wanna ensure your components fit classic appearance, use `<aura:application extends="ltng:outAppUnstyled" >` and Visualforce CSS classes in your component markup (behind a context aware toggle).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why they bothered making a distinction between a Lightning "App" and a Lightning "Component" since they are essential the same thing. You can build a component that implements force:appHostable and then use Lightning out to render it in a visualforce page and make it a tab in SF1 and LEX. You'll need to create an app with the dependencies defined for lightning out, and if your component fires SF1 / LEX events you'll need to add handlers in the visualforce page.

Comment: So the answer to my question "Is this the only way (using Visualforce and making it lightning ready).." is "Yes"? I need to use Visualforce?

Comment: Yes with lightning out. You don't have to write new components but you have two wrap them in a visualforce page.