# Best approach to use/port/migrate an open-source React component to LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, ui, react

I want to use an existing `React` Component as a LWC Lightning Web Component in a Salesforce app. It's a complex component with a Github repo full of Subcomponents. Everything is written in Typescript.

**Is there any chance to use, repurpose, migrate that to LWC? And what would be the process to do that?**

Comment: I presume you meant `chance` instead of `change`?

Comment: [This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/270532/2984) (not mine) includes some POC of how loading React might work. The answer is a bit old, but it still looks relevant.

Comment: No magic button, you will have to redo it! Having React within LWC is a nightmare so I would just redo it again! If you need to just port it to lightning then use lightning:container to host it!

Comment: Locker makes it really hard to use any such implementation that might not adhere to SecureWindow/document and other security policies so even if something works it cannot be said to be a reliable solution, you might want to rewrite the component in LWC

Answer (score 4):

Recently i implemented a solution for a client, that wraps React components (or any other Framework) in a LWC, without much change of the react code.
When I have more time I plan to open source it, but it's not yet.

The approach is very similar to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/11/how-to-use-apex-natively-with-svelte-vue-and-preact-within-lwc.html

In the blog post they build the react code using rollup.js to get an ES6 Module for the component, which exports a method to mount the react-component to a HTMLElement inside the LWC.

For my client, the react-components are not that simple, include some assets and are also rather big, which is a problem because of the code length limitation for LWCs (i think it is the same as for text fields ca. 32000 chars).
Therefore there we build the react code using a customized webpack-config that generates a bundle in form of a IIFE. The entrypoint adds a method to the window (something like `window.mountMyReactComponent(htmlElement, props)`). This is deployed as static resource and then gets loaded inside the wrapping LWC like other 3rd party code using `loadScript()`. (see Example)

So for simple components the way described in the blog post is more elegant and nice, but you can also make it work for complex components.

The important points:

- You'll need to configure your bundler to build the components code into bundles of the right format (how complex this is depends on the complexity of the react things), webpack does a lot things, that also means there is lots of things to configure...
- This only works for React >= 17 (older versions don't like to be hosted inside a ShadowDOM, though there is a workaround)

Example React Entrypoint (Typescript):

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import MyReactComponent from './components/MyReactComponent';

(window as any).mountMyReactComponent = (el: HTMLElement, injected: any) => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
            <MyReactComponent {...injected} />
        </React.StrictMode>,
        el,
    );
};
```

Example LWC

```html
<template>
    <div lwc:dom="manual" class="react-container"></div>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import ReactComponents from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/ReactComponents";

export default class MyReactComponent extends LightningElement {
  frameworkInitialized = false;

  renderedCallback() {
    if (this.frameworkInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    this.frameworkInitialized = true;

    this.mountFramework();
  }

  async mountFramework() {
    const rootElement = this.template.querySelector(".react-container");
    try {
      await Promise.all([
        loadStyle(this, `${ReactComponents}/css/my-react-component.css`),
        loadScript(this, `${ReactComponents}/js/my-react-component.bundle.js`),
      ]);
      window.mountMyReactComponent(rootElement, { somePropForReact: 'Banana' });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("problem loading react", error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer.

Comment: To add, if you have a lot of React components and need to share contexts or stores among them, look into https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html, the ``createPortal`` function. You can use it to assign a React element to a DOM node but it remains in the context of the react app.

So the idea would be to create a stub (e.g. <div id="react-root"></div>) and then in each LWC trigger a callback to create a portal using custom window events or similar. Should work in theory.